# which is more fast in rendering xml layout block or phtml create layout block in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, performance

I need to know which method is faster.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header_top')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Or the layout rendering.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="header_top" as="header_top" before="header">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>header_top</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Comment: second once is faster

Comment: Why it is more faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK second one is faster.

Your question is **Why?** ,

Then here is my answer,

**IN second method.**

because when page is load at that time all layouts were merged into one and all necessary blocks were called.

**In First Method**

When necessary Phtml or PHP file were called at that time this block is called and also this block cache lifetime depend on parent block where its called.

So at my point of view second Method is faster.